# Is the group $(\mathbb{C},+)=\langle1,i\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

I'm trying to see if I understand the notation. I think that

$$(\mathbb{C},+)=\langle1,i\rangle$$

Is this true?

Comment: Looks right to me.

EDIT: Apologies, misread the problem. No, you can't generate the complex numbers in general, but that does generate the complex numbers with integer components.

Comment: No, $\langle 1,i\rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$ since the latter is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains both $1$ and $i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the group operation in question is addition, $\langle 1,i \rangle$ generates only the complex numbers with *integer* real and imaginary parts: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. In fact, the additive group $\mathbb{C}$ is not finitely-generated: it cannot be generated by any finite subset.

If we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a *vector space* over $\mathbb{R}$, then it is generated by the set $\{1,i\}$.

If we think of $\mathbb{C}$ as an *unital algebra* over $\mathbb{R}$, then it is generated solely by $i$.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. The group generated by $1$ and $i$ is the group $\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.